# Create data frames in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function that takes in a `df` --> modifies the `df` --> and returns back the modified `df`.

I have a list `dfs` containing 5 `df` - I want to loop over them so that each is modified by the function, something like this:

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5]  # df1 to df5 : valid DataFrames

for df in dfs:
    df = function(df)
```

When I do that the content of the list `dfs` is not changed, I just end up with a new variable called 'df' that contains the *modified* information of `df5` (The last `df` in the list).

What am I doing wrong?  Is there a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign the modified `df` back to the name `df` but that will not change the item in the list it represents. You need to store your modified *local* `df` back to your list:

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5]

for idx, df in enumerate(dfs):
    dfs[idx] = function(df)       # immediately store result in list
```

would solve your problem.

---

Full demo:

```
import pandas as pd

dfs = [pd.DataFrame({"t":[n]}) for n in range(1,6)]

def function(df):
    df["t"] = df["t"] * 100
    return df
  
print(*dfs,"", sep= "\n\n")

for idx, df in enumerate(dfs):
    dfs[idx] = function(df)

print(*dfs, sep="\n\n")
```

Output:

```
  t
0  1

  t
0  2

  t
0  3
    
  t
0  4

  t
0  5


    t
0  100

    t
0  200

    t
0  300

    t
0  400

    t
0  500
```